# Can you recommend a JavaScript JPEG library without an HTML or atob dependency?

Tags: javascript, binary, titanium, jpeg, appcelerator

I'm having some issues reading JPEG binary data with JavaScript and looking for some recommendations on libraries or alternative approaches.

I am working to modify an open source PDF generation library called [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) so that it will work with an Appcelerator Titanium Alloy 3.41 project. The issue I am running into is that while Titanium uses JavaScript the implementation does not support all data types or methods.

For example, most of the JPEG libraries I have found use the [atob and btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64.atob) methods which are implemented in web browsers to encode/decode base64 data into binary strings. Unfortunately the project I am creating does not use a web browser and even if I changed my approach Titanium's WebView does not support the atob or btoa methods.

I've also tried using Titanium's [base64encode and base64decode](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Utils-method-base64encode) utilities however they return a [Blob](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Blob) instead of a binary string and most methods I have seen for converting base64 to a binary string requires an ArrayBuffer which Titanium also does not implement.

I'm following the following steps to generate a PDF:

1. Create a dataURI by reading in the JPEG into a [Blob](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Blob) and converting it to base64.

   var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEA.....ooA//2Q==';
2. The library then extracts the image data from the dataURI. The library then uses the atob method to convert the base64 into a binary string and then if the environment supports ArrayBuffers a function is used to convert the ArrayBuffer to a Uint8Array which Titanium does support. From there the binary data is used to extract the JPEG height, width, etc.

[Code extract from jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/jspdf.plugin.addimage.js#L566)

```
var base64Info = this.extractInfoFromBase64DataURI(imageData);
if(base64Info) {
  format = base64Info[2];
  imageData = atob(base64Info[3]);//convert to binary string, the base64 encoded JPEG 
 } 

.....

if(this.supportsArrayBuffer()) {
  dataAsBinaryString = imageData;
  imageData = this.binaryStringToUint8Array(imageData);
}

.....

function binaryStringToUint8Array(binary_string) {
  var len = binary_string.length;
  var bytes = new Uint8Array( len );
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bytes;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem in IE 9 with jspdf.plugin.addimage.js, where atob is not implemented. Would you be able to try this polyfill? https://github.com/davidchambers/Base64.js

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure javascript example.

```
// Create Base64 Object
var Base64= {_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/++[++^A-Za-z0-9+/=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/\r\n/g,"n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}}

// Define the string
var string = 'Hello World!';

// Encode the String
var encodedString = Base64.encode(string);
console.log(encodedString); // Outputs: "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh"

// Decode the String
var decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedString);
console.log(decodedString); // Outputs: "Hello World!"
```

https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-encode-and-decode-strings-with-base64-in-javascript